# Problem with JacksonXmlElementWrapper on Kotlin

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to parse a XML file using Jackson and Kotlin on Android Studio. In particular, I want to run the code from the following test case in jackson-module-kotlin:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/test/github/Github153.kt

```kotlin
    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "MyPojo")
    data class MyDataPojo (
            @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "elements")
            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
            val elements : List<MyDataElement>
    )

    data class MyDataElement (
            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "value", isAttribute = true)
            var value: String
    )
```

I'm trying to parse a XML file like this:

```kotlin
    val xmlMapper = XmlMapper().apply {
        registerModule(KotlinModule())
    }
    val pojo = context.resources.assets.open(name).use { input ->
        xmlMapper.readValue<MyDataPojo>(input)
    }
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid definition for property `elements` (of type `eu.tilk.wihajster.MyDataPojo`): Could not find creator property with name 'elements' (known Creator properties: [element])
```

I'm using Jackson 2.10.3, here is my dependencies section from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.10.3'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.3"
    implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? This code is copied from a test for jackson-module-kotlin, so I believe it should work fine.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/153) with the Jackson Kotlin Module:

> **[apatrida](https://github.com/apatrida)** commented on [14 Jul 2018](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/153#issuecomment-405043264)
> `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` cannot be on a parameter therefore no property name of `elements` gets added to the creator parameter, and instead `JacksonXmlProperty` ends up on the parameter which is the wrong name. So then the mapper tries to pass in `elements` but the parameter appears to be property `element`

The test you have linked is actually expected to fail for data classes:

```kotlin
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "MyPojo")
data class MyDataPojo (
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "elements")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
        val elements : List<MyDataElement>
)

@Test
// Conflict between the annotations that is not current resolvable.
fun test_data_class() {
    expectFailure<InvalidDefinitionException>("Problem with conflicting annotations related to #153 has been fixed!") {
        // I create a pojo from the xml using the data classes
        val pojoFromXml = mapper.readValue(xml, MyDataPojo::class.java)

        // I create a xml from the pojo
        val xmlFromPojo = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojoFromXml)

        // I compare the original xml with the xml generated from the pojo
        assertEquals(xml, xmlFromPojo)
    }
}
```

It is however expected to work for *non*-data classes:

```kotlin
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "MyPojo")
class MyPojo {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "elements")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
    var list: List<MyElement>? = null
}

@Test
fun test_class() {
    // I create a pojo from the xml using the standard classes
    val pojoFromXml = mapper.readValue(xml, MyPojo::class.java)

    // I create a xml from the pojo
    val xmlFromPojo = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojoFromXml)

    // I compare the original xml with the xml generated from the pojo
    assertEquals(xml, xmlFromPojo)
}
```

As you can see—even though Kotlin makes it a little difficult—the difference is that `elements` is a constructor parameter in the data class, but a field in the regular class.

The best workaround I can think of without creating custom (de)serializers is

- Making the primary constructor private
- Letting the field be `lateinit var` with a private setter
- Manually overriding `hashCode()`, `equals()` and `toString()`

For example:

```kotlin
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "MyPojo")
class WorkaroundPojo private constructor() {
    constructor(list: List<MyElement>) : this() {
        this.list = list
    }

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "elements")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
    lateinit var list: List<MyElement>
        private set

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as WorkaroundPojo

        if (list != other.list) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return list.hashCode()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "WorkaroundPojo(list=$list)"
    }
}

@Test
fun test_workaround() {
    val pojoFromXml = mapper.readValue(xml, WorkaroundPojo::class.java)
    val xmlFromPojo = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojoFromXml)
    assertEquals(xml, xmlFromPojo)
}
```

Here is a JUnit5 test with a more complex example showing how to combine the above with inheritance, enums and more using Jackson 2.13.0:

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.kotlinModule
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue

class StackOverflow {

    abstract class ActivatableElement {
        abstract val active: Boolean
    }

    class ComplexExample private constructor(
        override val active: Boolean = false,
        val myEnum: MyEnum = MyEnum.First,
    ) : ActivatableElement() {

        constructor(active: Boolean, myEnum: MyEnum, myElements: List<MyElement>) : this(active, myEnum) {
            this.elements = myElements
        }

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "elementList")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
        lateinit var elements: List<MyElement>
            private set

        data class MyElement(
            val name: String,
            val number: Int
        )

        enum class MyEnum {
            @XmlEnumValue("First value of MyEnum")
            First,

            @XmlEnumValue("Second value of MyEnum")
            Second,
        }

        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
            if (this === other) return true
            if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

            other as ComplexExample

            if (active != other.active) return false
            if (myEnum != other.myEnum) return false
            if (elements != other.elements) return false

            return true
        }

        override fun hashCode(): Int {
            var result = active.hashCode()
            result = 31 * result + myEnum.hashCode()
            result = 31 * result + elements.hashCode()
            return result
        }
    }

    val xml = """
        <ComplexExample>
          <active>true</active>
          <myEnum>Second value of MyEnum</myEnum>
          <elementList>
            <element>
              <name>First Item</name>
              <number>1</number>
            </element>
            <element>
              <name>Second Item</name>
              <number>2</number>
            </element>
            <element>
              <name>Third Item</name>
              <number>3</number>
            </element>
          </elementList>
        </ComplexExample>
    """.trimIndent()

    @Test
    fun test_complex_example() {
        val mapper = XmlMapper.builder()
            .addModule(kotlinModule())
            .addModule(JaxbAnnotationModule())
            .build()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)

        val example = mapper.readValue(xml, ComplexExample::class.java)
        val xmlFromExample = mapper.writeValueAsString(example).trim()
        Assertions.assertEquals(xml, xmlFromExample)

        val expected = ComplexExample(
            active = true,
            myEnum = ComplexExample.MyEnum.Second,
            myElements = listOf(
                ComplexExample.MyElement("First Item", 1),
                ComplexExample.MyElement("Second Item", 2),
                ComplexExample.MyElement("Third Item", 3),
            )
        )
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, example)
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected.hashCode(), example.hashCode())
    }
}
```